# Loop through a GeoPandas dataframe and increment the row you're looking at

Tags: python, database, geopandas

I'm looping through a geopandas dataframe, called `street_map`. With this, I would like to include it in a loop so each time I only look at 1 row within my data frame.

I have tried iterrors() but it appears the issue is the geometry column as it cannot index my rows.

I have tried various ways of resolving this. My geopandas has a key, called SA4_CODE21, which is an increment of 101 onward, but randomises sometimes, so there may be 191, 210, 291, so I cannot simply increment by + 1.

How would I iterate through each row to select the next row of data?

My current progress:
This has not worked!

```
for i in range(len(street_map)):

    # isolate top row, loop through to go n+1, each loop to output an image and supporting points etc

    # street_map = street_map.iloc[i:(i+1)]

    print(i)
    print(i+1)

    # print(row['SA4_NAME21'], row['SA4_CODE21'])
    # print(i+1)
    street_map = street_map[street_map.SA4_CODE21.between((i), (i+1), inclusive=True)]
    print(street_map.head())
```

Does anyone know the way to simply increment through each row with GEOPANDAS?

A simple 1 row iterate for my geopandas dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Iterating a GeoDataFrame works the same as iterating a normal pandas DataFrame. A lot of info and examples can be found in the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#iteration).

This is a simple example using itertuples on a GeoDataFrame shows some ways to use the data/index of the row/GeoDataFrame from within the loop:

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("nybb"))
for row in gdf.itertuples():
    print(f"row with index {row.Index} has BoroName <{row.BoroName}> and Shape_Area is <{gdf['Shape_Area'][row.Index]}>")
```

Result:

```
row with index 0 has BoroName <Staten Island> and Shape_Area is <1623819823.81>
row with index 1 has BoroName <Queens> and Shape_Area is <3045212795.2>
row with index 2 has BoroName <Brooklyn> and Shape_Area is <1937478507.61>
row with index 3 has BoroName <Manhattan> and Shape_Area is <636471539.774>
row with index 4 has BoroName <Bronx> and Shape_Area is <1186924686.49>
```